# Eclipse Forms-Editable title for user input

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am wondering if there is a way to make the Form Title editable for user input? Or can I only use a text field?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume this is `org.eclipse.ui.forms` that you are asking about.

The title area of the form heading just uses a `Label` control, so, no, it can't be editable.